# Spring MVC, JSON, wrong serialization of string fields, that are longer than 1000 characters

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I try to send list of entities as JSON data from server to client via annotation @ResponseBody. Problem is that text fields, longer than 1000 serialize incorrectly. In this case string replase on null symbols "\u0000" sequence.

I configure JSON mapper:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan({"configs", "controllers", "services", "models"})
public class WebConfig
{
    @Bean RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter()
    {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter reqMapHAdapter=new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();

        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.indentOutput(true);
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter httpMsgConv=new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build());
        httpMsgConv.setPrettyPrint(true);

        ArrayList<MediaType> mediaTypes=new ArrayList<>();
        mediaTypes.add(new MediaType("application", "json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        httpMsgConv.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);

        ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>> msgConvs=new ArrayList<>();
        msgConvs.add(httpMsgConv);

        reqMapHAdapter.setMessageConverters(msgConvs);
        return reqMapHAdapter;
    }
    ...
}
```

Controller's method:

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    @RequestMapping(value={GET_MESSAGES_URL}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody List<MessageViewItem> getMessages()
    {
        // getting List<MesssageViewItem>
        List<MessageViewItem> messages=...;
        return messages;
    }
}
```

MessageViewItem class:

```
public class MessageViewItem 
{
    private String  text,
                    localizedSendingDate;

    private UserShortViewItem author;

    private Long  messageId;

    // default constructor, getters and setters ...
}
```

And results, if text.length()<=1000:

```
[ {
  "text" : "123",
  "localizedSendingDate" : "1 day ago",
  "author" : {
    "viewName" : "John Doe",
    "imageUrl" : "/test_web_spring/images/usersImages/0/0/4.jpg",
    "id" : 940
  },
  "messageId" : 3540
} ]
```

If text.length()>1000 ( I cut large part "\u0000" from message ):

```
[ {
  "text" : " : \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000",
  "localizedSendingDate" : "3 hour ago",
  "author" : {
    "viewName" : "John Doe",
    "imageUrl" : "/test_web_spring/images/usersImages/0/0/4.jpg",
    "id" : 940
  },
  "messageId" : 3812
} ]
```

Altough, manually call ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString work as expected and serialize text field longer than 1000 characters normally.

Any ideas, how to fix this issue?

ADD: Test controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/testJsonConv"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody MessageViewItem testJsonConv()
{
    MessageViewItem msgViewItem=new MessageViewItem();
    msgViewItem.setText("Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur?Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo");      
    return msgViewItem;
}
```

result(cut large part "\u0000"):

```
{
  "text" : " : \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000",
  "localizedSendingDate" : null,
  "author" : null,
  "messageId" : null
}
```

Comment: The problem is not with the text length. Try to hardcode one long string with more than 1000 chars in the `text` field and check the result and post back here.

Comment: I add result in main post. Or you did not mean it?

Comment: for me working without concerns...is there anything you made  in the config files?

Comment: I also think that my problem in configuration, because manually injected RequestMappingHandlerAdapter produce correct JSON. But I don't know, where to look a issue.

Comment: I'm find non elegant but working solution: manually convert data to JSON string and return it using StringHttpMessageConverter. Notify this as answer if complete solution will not found after some time. @NokolayRusev, thank for you'r help.

Comment: if you start a project from scratch, without adding custom config it will work i'm pretty sure, because i started simple spring boot project and it works...

Comment: @alexeyIvanov have u got a solution?? I´m with this same problem!!

Comment: @eduyayo, hello! I'm used described above solution. My solution is as follows: 1. set return content type as text/plain in controller method. 2. manually convert data to json string. 3. return it.

Comment: Yup thx... I did the same yesterday. Still missing a reason for this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible solution:

1. Use explicit convertation to JSON, like this:

   @Controller
   public class MyController
   {
       @Autowired ObjectMapper mapper;

   ```
   // manually convert you'r data to JSON string, and send as text
   @RequestMapping(value={GET_MESSAGES_URL}, 
       method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) throws ...
   @ResponseBody String getMessages()
   {
       // getting List<MesssageViewItem>
       List<MessageViewItem> messages=...;
       return mapper.writeValueAsString(messages);
   }
   ```

   }

don't forget add messages converter for text media type:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan({"configs", "models"})
public class WebConfig 
{
    @Bean RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter()
    {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter reqMapHAdapter=new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();

        ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>> msgConvs=new ArrayList<>();

        StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        msgConvs.add(stringConverter);

        reqMapHAdapter.setMessageConverters(msgConvs);
        return reqMapHAdapter;
    }

    ...
}
```

2. After update dependencies for my project problem is dissapired. I update spring to 4.2.4 and(probably most important) - jackson, from codehaus to last fasterxml version.

Here was a post, that I would like mark as answer. Author advised update jackson library and it help me. But,
unfortunately, I cannot find this post.